# blueprintjs table error with example code

Tags: blueprintjs

I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [Blueprint Table] <Table> Children of Table must be Columns"
    at table.js:879`
```

Using the code:

```
<Table numRows={5}>
  <Column />
  <Column />
  <Column />
</Table>
```

and version 2.0.0 of `@blueprintjs/table`

Answer (score 1):

What are your imports? Make sure you are importing `Column` from `@blueprintjs/table`.